# Building ClickOnce desktop application using azure pipeline not generating setup.exe even after adding msbuildArgs parameter?

Tags: azure-devops, clickonce

When we are trying to build ClickOnce desktop .net 6 application in Azure DevOps CI pipeline, Below is the YAML step for the build but still i am not getting the main application executable ?

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build ClickOnce'
  inputs:
    solution: 'applicationxxx.sln'
    #msbuildArgs: '/t:publish /p:PublishProfile=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\ClickOnceProfile.pubxml /p:PublishDir="$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)"'
    msbuildArgs: '/target:publish /p:PublishProfile=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\ClickOnceProfile.pubxml /p:UpdateEnabled=true '
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy ClickOnce Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) copy'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\ClickOnce'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click once application build using CLI throwed error of one of dll is not compatible with .net 6, after doing the following step I was able to successfully build & publish the ClickOnce application in the Azure DevOps pipeline

1. Updated the Visual Studio to the latest version / use latest version agent
2. Deleted the publishing profile *.pubxml from properties and created a new profile
3. It is mandatory to keep the clickoncepublishing.pubxml file in the property folder only not any other location in repo
4. Used CLI to build and publish

Note - even if we point the publishing profile to the wrong file/file that does not exist, it will still build successfully- no error is shown.Make sure we point to right file path

```
msbuild /t:publish /p:PublishProfile=<pubxml file> /p:PublishDir="<specific location>"
```

reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2022